# Computing Div and Mod Complexity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Show that Algorithm below uses $\mathcal{O}(q \log a)$ bit operations, assuming that $a > d$.

For the div and mod algorithm below, could you please explain why we have $log a$ in the complexity, which is $\mathcal{O}(q \log a)$? I understand $q$ comes from the number of times we have the while loop, but I am not sure why $log a$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\log a$ comes from the worst-case number of bit operations it takes to subtract $d$ from $r$ in each of the $q$ iterations.

There is also an implied integer comparison in the whole loop that costs about the same $O(\log a)$ operations.  Note that we do need $a \ge d$ to make this claim accurate, for two reasons:

- If $a < 0$ then the expression $O(q \log a $ is somewhat meaningless.
- If $0 \le a < d$, then $q = 0$ and it isn’t true that it takes $O(0)$ operations (i.e. the inner loop is not the dominant cost).

We also need $a > 1$ for similar reasons (to avoid $\log a = 0$), which the question doesn’t state explicitly but might be rolled into the particular definition of big-Oh notation used in the text.

Assuming $a>0$, the size of $r$ starts at $a$, thus $1 + \lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor$ bits.  And it does get smaller from there, so each subsequent subtraction also deals with integers of $O(\log a)$ bits.

One could in theory obtain a tighter, more complicated bound by exploiting the fact that  subtracting a 10-bit number from a 100-bit number rarely requires 100 bit operations unless there are a substantial number of “borrows”.  But that would be a little bit besides the point, as we’re trying to prove a specific upper bound rather than the exact running time.